# Make default element change when other elements are mousedover

Tags: css, hover

Found this great jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4mE3b/4/ that approximates my needs. I need one aspect that this fiddle doesn't offer and I cannot find the answer.

I want the first element, in this case it's the red block, to be like a default image, so when the page is loaded, it appears as red. But, when other elements are hovered over, I want it to change it's state.

> HTML

```
<div class="red blur-me"></div>
<div class="blue blur-me"></div>
<div class="green blur-me"></div>
<div class="orange blur-me"></div>
<div class="black blur-me"></div>
```

> Javascript

```
blurredImages = $( '.blur-me' ); 
blurredImages.on( "mouseenter", function () {
$( this ).addClass( "blurred" );    
})  
blurredImages.on( "mouseleave", function () { 
$( this ).removeClass( "blurred" );     
})
```

> CSS

```
.red, .blue, .green, .orange, .black {

width: 80px;
height: 80px;
margin: 6px;}

.red {
background-color: red;}

.red blur-me {background:green;}

.blue {
background-color: blue;
opacity: 1;}

.green {
background-color: green;
opacity: 1;}

.orange {
background-color: orange;
opacity: 1;}

.black {
background-color: black;
opacity: 1;}

.blurred {
opacity: 0.5;}
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You should place them all in a wrapper div and toggle its class on mouseenter and mouselave as such

```
HTML
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="red blur-me"></div>
   <div class="blue blur-me"></div>
   <div class="green blur-me"></div>
   <div class="orange blur-me"></div>
   <div class="black blur-me"></div>
</div>

jQuery
$('.blur-me').hover(function(){ 
  var that = $(this);
   $('#wrapper').removeClass();
   $('#wrapper').addClass(that.attr('class').split(' ')[0] + '-hovered');
});
```

This will add the a class name of red-hovered to the wrapper div on hovering the red, this way you can respond to each element when hovered and change the CSS accordingly, for example:

```
.red-hovered .red{
    opacity: .9;
}
```

I hope this is what you asked for

Comment: Thanks Zyad but I couldn't get your code to work. Was your jQuery supposed to be added to mine or is that all I'll need? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I made a small mistake on var that = $this ... should be $(this) instead, edited my answer and tested on jsfiddle check this link http://jsfiddle.net/4mE3b/39/